# Centre of a Lie algebra

Tags: lie-algebras, rt.representation-theory

Let $f\in \mathbb{C}[x_1,\dots, x_n]$ be a reduced homogeneous polynomial of degree n.

Let $\mathfrak{g}=\{ \delta \in Der_{\mathbb{C}^n}|\delta(f)\in (f)\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{C}^n} \text{ and weight}(\delta) =0 \}$ be a (reductive) complex Lie algebra with minimal system of generators $\langle \sigma_1, \dots, \sigma_s, \delta_1, \dots, \delta_r\rangle$ such that:

1. $\sigma_1, \dots, \sigma_s$ are simultaneously diagonalizable,
2. $\delta_1, \dots, \delta_r$ are nilpotent,
3. $[\sigma_i,\delta_j]\in \mathbb{Q} \cdot \delta_j$ for all i,j.

Is it true that the centre of $\mathfrak{g}$ is made only of diagonalizable elements?

Comment: What do you mean by made of diagonal elements? Clearly, nothing in your formulation prevents $\delta_1$ to be in the centre, but then it is diagnosable itself

Comment: I meant that the centre is a subset of $\langle \sigma_1, \dots, \sigma_s \rangle$. Moreover, in my case $\mathfrak{g}$ is a Lie algebra of weight zero vector fields.

Comment: Why can't you take $\mathfrak{g}$ to be abelian and $r\geq 1$?

Comment: Again what do you mean by "simultaneously diagonalizable"?
Is your Lie algebra meant to be a subalgebra of some
$\mathfrak{gl}_n$?

Comment: @Jose': in the case that I'm interested $s\ge 1$.
@Robin: yes, I think oh $\sigma_i$ and $\delta_j$ as $n\times n$ matrices.

Comment: One possible meaning (the one I took) for "simultaneously diagonalisable"  is that they are commuting semisimple elements.  I stand to be corrected, though.

Comment: @Michele: You can have $s\geq 1$ and still have an abelian algebra.  This satisfies all 3 of your conditions.  I suspect that there is an extra condition that is implicit.

Comment: @Jose': implicit condition like what?the fact is that my Lie algebra arise attached to a singular hypersurface.

Comment: @Michele: Then why is this information missing from the question?  My guess is that you are hoping to prove a result about a particular Lie algebra by applying some result about general  Lie algebras.  (Your recent questions all suggest this.)  It does not seem to me that you are spending enough time testing your conjectures, though.


Comment: @Michele, can you make the statement of the question precise (in particular, incorporating the information you've given in the comments)?

Comment: sorry if I did't put all the information, but I was thinking it was a true fact in a more general settings. Some of my previous questions where in reality related to an article that was stating something wrong...